# Packaging a captive runtime bundle for desktop computers from ADT command line

Tags: apache-flex, air, package

I friends, 
i have less this tutorial [packaging a captive runtime bundle for desktop computers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f-63d4a6d6131f383b813-8000) which is a guide to create an installation package includes the AIR runtime.

I have develop AIR Desktop Application with Flash Builder 4.5 and i have used SDK version 4.5.0 and relative ADT version for packaging the application. I followed the tutorial of adobe (link above) but does not recognize the command -target bundle. Why? I replaced sdk 3.6.0 is the adt command works with the option but can not create the package because I use only the components present in version 4.5.0 of the SDK. How do I create the package with the same features of the guide??

Comment: If you're using Flash Builder; why do you want to / need to use the command line?  Can't you just use Flash Builder and export a release build?

Comment: My principal feature include the runtime in installation package

Comment: Yes, there is a checkbox for "Captive Runtime" when you export a release build.

Comment: In Flash Builder 4.5 this checkbox is not present, i have used version 4.6 and it's works! ty

Comment: I posted it as a formal answer, please accept it at your earliest convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Captive Runtime option was not introduced until Flash Builder 4.6; so you can't do it using the Flash Builder 4.5.