# How to include Adobe Air in the package when creating a native installer desktop application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I successfully created an Adobe Air application to install/run in Windows through the native installer. However, I would like to know if it is possible to avoid having the client install Adobe Air. Is it possible to include the necessary Air library in the .exe file so the application is not dependent on downloading/installing Air?

Comment: I read this about native extensions: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS597e5dadb9cc1e0253f7d2fc1311b491071-8000.html)... but I'm not clear if it will work for desktop applications (because it says "desktop devices").

Comment: Native Extensions should work for desktop deployment, although probably not the same ones that are built for mobile.  I'm very confused how Native Extensions relate to your question.  You want to look up Captive Runtime which removes depedencies on an external AIR Runtime and allows you to create a native installer for your platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - all you have to do is select "Captive Runtime" when you choose "Export Release Build" for the application.  Note that this requires Flash Builder 4.6 or later.

If you're using the command line to build your app, there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371591/packaging-a-captive-runtime-bundle-for-desktop-computers-from-adt-command-line) here on StackOverflow that should help.

[image: Choosing Captive Runtime in Export Release Build in Flash Builder]

Comment: ahah! I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 so the option for captive runtime is not available. I guess I'll look into that command line utility. Good to know what I want is possible. Thanks!